# Is it possible to Build and Run Linux on ARM Cortex-R and ARM Cortex-M devices and How?

Tags: linux, arm

Both these Profiles belong to ARMv7.As per Technical Reference Manual of both, they are not having Memory Management Unit (MMU) & they dont have ARM Instruction Set.They run on Thumb-1 & Thumb-2 Instruction Set.

Comment: No. Those are microcontrollers with 4k-64k RAM. Even if you manage to fit a stripped version of some Unix into it (there used to be Unix and Linux "ports" to MMU-less archs like z80 or 8086), there would be no space left to do anything useful. On such platforms you run your apps on bare metal.

Comment: @pizdelect So Bare Metal app need bare metal compiler, like gcc [arm-none-eabi-].GCC like [arm-cross-linux-muslgnueabi-] wont do, right?